# Python + TKinter + OMXPlayer window on top

Tags: python, omxplayer

I own a raspberry pi 2 and i start learning Python. I would like to do something very basic : the window of my Python program on top of omxplayer window like a notification system.

I have been able to make an "always on top" window with TKinter but when i launch omxplayer my window is no more on top.

I would apreciate some help !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try**:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
```

Source: http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/always_on_top

Comment: Hello E. Otero, I have already tried this solution. The window is over others but when i launch omxplayer the window stay under omxplayer window's. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tried something new, below is the code : 
`code`
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
import threading

root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)

def focus():
    threading.Timer(0.1, focus).start()
    root.focus_force()

focus()
root.mainloop()
`code`
But it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to used Hello_font from the hello_pi examples on the raspberry pi.