# How to make omxplayer not always on top?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, omxplayer

I am using [Adafruit's Video Looper](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-video-looper/overview) to loop on a video using python script and omxplayer. Although, I made a few modifications. I want a popup window to appear when a GPIO button is pressed.

I have the GPIO and the python script for a tkinter window all done and working, but the omxplayer is always on top so my window don't appear.

I tested without the omxplayer active and I guarantee the popup window is working (has 'always on top' on).

Is there any options on omxplayer to adjust that? Or should I take a totally different approach?

(I am also posting this question on [Raspberry Pi Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75608/how-to-make-omxplayer-not-always-on-top). I don't know which forum is better suited for the question)

EDIT 1: Same exact [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031727/python-tkinter-omxplayer-window-on-top). But no solutions. I tried the same things as the other user.

Comment: This is more an operating system thing, you should search for `set window above others` or similar.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? Why is it a OS thingy?